# How to fix wrong indexPath returned by didSelectRowAt?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView; without a tableHeaderView tapping a row and triggering didSelectRowAt returns the correct index path.

When I set the tableHeaderView property, didSelectRowAt either does not fire or returns the tappedRow + 2. Where am I going wrong?

Here is my code

```
class MenuController: UIViewController {
    // Mark -- Properties
    var tableView: UITableView!
    var delegate: HomeControllerDelegate?
    var headerView: HeaderView? = nil
    var user: User? = nil

    // Mark -- Init

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureTableView()
        if let user = self.user {
            populateMenuHeader(email: user.email, firstName: user.firstName, lastName: user.lastName, imageUrl: user.imageUrl)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        //updateHeaderViewHeight(for: tableView.tableHeaderView)
    }

    func updateHeaderViewHeight(for header: UIView?) {
        guard let headerView = headerView else { return }
        headerView.frame.size.height = 170
    }

    func populateMenuHeader(email: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, imageUrl: String) {
        headerView?.emailLabel?.text = email
        headerView?.nameLabel?.text = "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
        let request = ImageRequest(
            url: URL(string: imageUrl)!,
            processors: [
                ImageProcessor.Resize(size: CGSize(width: 70, height: 70)),
                ImageProcessor.Circle()
            ]
        )
        Nuke.loadImage(with: request, into: headerView!.imageView!)
    }

    // Mark -- Handlers
    func configureTableView() {
        // Create Material Header
        headerView = HeaderView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 170))
        //headerView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 170).isActive = true
        headerView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 170

        tableView.register(MenuOptionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        tableView.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.rowHeight = 80

        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

extension MenuController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MenuOptionCell
        let menuOption = MenuOption(rawValue: indexPath.row)
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = menuOption?.description
        cell.iconImageView.image = menuOption?.image
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let row = indexPath.row
        print("tapped row: \(row)")
        let menuOption = MenuOption(rawValue: row)
        delegate?.handleMenuToggle(forMenuOption: menuOption)
    }
}

class CustomView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
            context.setLineWidth(1)
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height))
            context.strokePath()
        }
    }
}

class HeaderView : UIView {
    var imageView: UIImageView? = nil
    var nameLabel: UILabel? = nil
    var emailLabel: UILabel? = nil

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nameLabel = UILabel()
        nameLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nameLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 20)
        nameLabel?.text = "Test name"
        nameLabel?.textColor = .white
        emailLabel = UILabel()
        emailLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        emailLabel?.textColor = .white
        emailLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 15)
        emailLabel?.text = "testemail@gmail.com"
        self.addSubview(imageView!)
        self.addSubview(nameLabel!)
        self.addSubview(emailLabel!)
        let lineView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.height - 1, width: frame.width, height: 1))
        self.addSubview(lineView)


        imageView?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        imageView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        imageView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, constant: 70).isActive = true
        imageView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, constant: 70).isActive = true

        nameLabel?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        nameLabel?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView!.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

        emailLabel?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        emailLabel?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel!.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
          fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be due to the fact that you are not properly setting the height of the header view. The documentation for `tableHeaderView` states:

> When assigning a view to this property, set the height of that view to a nonzero value. The table view respects only the height of your view's frame rectangle; it adjusts the width of your header view automatically to match the table view's width.

Update your header view code:

Change:

```
headerView = HeaderView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 170))
//headerView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 170).isActive = true
headerView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

...

tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 170
```

to just:

```
headerView = HeaderView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 170))
```

That's it. No need to mess with constraints. No need to set the unrelated section height. Just give the header view's frame the desired height.

Comment: Thank you! Disabling autolayout fixes row tapping. But now my HeaderView display is quite wonky. Why does enabling autolayout fix the row tapping issue?

I'd expect the tableView to properly match the tap to an indexPath with just the headerView being initialized with a CGRect with a height of 170.

Comment: Your comment contradicts itself. First you say that disabling auto layout fixes the rows tapping and then you ask why enabling it fixes the issue.

Comment: My apologies!

Why does enabling*** autolayout fix the row tapping issue?

Comment: But autolayout is not enabled. The fix was to rely (correctly) on the provided frame. When you did `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` then you are telling autolayout to ignore the view's frame and to rely on constraints.

Comment: Got it. I am misunderstanding something fundamental. Gonna hit the docs. Thank you for the guidance!