# UITableView didSelectRowAt returning wrong index path

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm using the `didSelectRowAt` method of `UITableView` to detect when a user's cell was tapped on and then show their profile. However, I've notified that sometimes, after scrolling then immediately tapping a cell, the provided index path in the method is incorrect. I'll scroll back up and click on cell at section 1 row 3 and the returned index path is at section 1 row 8, resulting in the wrong user being shown. What am I doing wrong here?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let user = users[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let data: [AnyHashable: Any] = ["user": user]
    
    print("Section: \(indexPath.section) | Row: \(indexPath.row)")
    print("User: \(user.firstName) \(user.lastName)")
    
    // Notify that a user has been tapped when cell is selected
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .userTapped, object: nil, userInfo: data)
}
```

With cellForRowAt (copied from comments):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuse, for: indexPath) as! UserCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    let user = users[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let icon: UserCell.Icon = (indexPath.section == 0) ? .beacon : .add

    cell.configure(for: user, swipeEnabled: true, icon: icon)
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Just as a sanity check how do you know that the index path is wrong are you logging the index path on the first line `let user = ...` ?

Comment: Can you also provide the cellForRowAt DataSource method?

Comment: @TMin I have the two print statements that print the index path and user

Comment: @MacUserT here it is:

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuse, for: indexPath) as! UserCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        
        let user = users[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        let icon: UserCell.Icon = (indexPath.section == 0) ? .beacon : .add
        
        cell.configure(for: user, swipeEnabled: true, icon: icon)
        
        return cell
}

Comment: Hard to decipher the code you posted in the comments, but the code you posted in your question - particularly the `print` statement looks good. If that's how you are gleaning this, maybe strip out the rest of the code (as described by @TMin) just to make sure something else isn't the real issue.

Comment: Did you try with dequeueReusableCell(withIdentidier:) ?

Comment: Hi tjc, I can’t see anything in the code you provided, that hints towards a potential solution for your problem. Probably, the error occurs somewhere else in the code, that the delegate can’t read the IndexPath correctly. Have you looked at this answer, if it brings you in the right direction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58760148/how-to-fix-wrong-indexpath-returned-by-didselectrowat

Comment: @PtitXav yes that is what I'm using to create the cells in cellForRowAt

Comment: @MacUserT thanks for the suggestion, but I am setting the header via the heightForHeaderInSection and viewForHeaderInSection delegate methods. unfortunately still can't get a fix

Comment: @tjc : I meant dequeue without indexPath argument

Comment: @PtitXav unfortunately no good but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Try by adding a deselection of the row in that delegate method via `deselectRow(at:animated:)`